# Moving mouse cursor with gamepad question

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I can create a gameobject that I can move around like a cursor with my xbox controller, however when it comes to pressing buttons I have 1 issue.

It seems there is no way to set the actual mouse cursor position without importing user32.dll and even that solution will only be a windows solution. https://answers.unity.com/questions/330661/setting-the-mouse-position-to-specific-coordinates.html

The reason I want to move the actual mouse cursor as well as my gameobject representing a cursor, is that I still want to be able to click buttons, and when I call Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0); it will click the button at the point where the actual mouse cursor is, and if the actual mouse cursor isnt moving with us its not gonna work.

Also I dont need a custom mouse cursor, if the xbox controller could move the mouse cursor directly thats fine too.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to set the mouse position maybe if you needed to have a solution for mac as well you can find it [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/564664/how-i-can-move-mouse-cursor-without-mouse-but-with.html) at the bottom.

also making a custom cursor is a better solution cause it will be cross platform and you could make a custom mouse down event for it so i don't see why you wouldn't

and if you are sure you need the actual mouse to move you only have the first solution 
and moving the mouse with xbox controller by using a software is only gonna work on your pc and those softwares are probably using the first solution

Comment: thanks for your reply. so what would need to be in the custom mouse down event in order to trigger the buttons when we click them?